# React-dnd element style is not updated on drag move

Tags: drag-and-drop, reactjs, redux, react-dnd

I have adapted [react-dnd](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd) [sortable example](http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-sortable-simple.html) to use inside of my application.

I can't make the "opacity" to follow my drag.

When I initially pick the element up opacity is applied:

[image: starting drag]

But when I move it up to change the position opacity is still applied to the original DOM element(?).

[image: moving over element while dragging]

State is changed accordingly, columns in a table associated with this state are being reordered. So apart of opacity everything else is working fine.

When I move the elements around only the values of the li are being changed but the `data-reactid` are not changing positions.

[image]

**The only difference in my app is the way how I manage the state. In my application state is managed via redux.**

The `hover` function that is passed in to the DropTarget is basically copy and paste from the example.

SortableColumnEntry component:

```
class SortableColumnEntry extends Component {
  render(){
    const { connectDragSource, connectDropTarget } = this.props
    const { column, isDragging, index } = this.props

    const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1

    const element = connectDropTarget(connectDragSource(
      <li
        style={{opacity: opacity}}</li>
    ))

    return element
  }
}

export default flow(
  DragSource(DragTypes.COLUMN, source, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  })),
  DropTarget(DragTypes.COLUMN, target, (connect) => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
  }))
)(SortableColumnEntry)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I finally sorted it.

There was a problem with a `key` value I have passed in from a parent component.

I used to base that `key` on the index which was changing with the element.

Thats how I used to do it:

```
const columnTags = columns.map(
  (column, index) => 
    <SortableColumnEntry 
    key={index} 
    index={index}
    column={column} />)
```

When I changed it to stay unique and associated to the state:

```
const columnTags = columns.map(
  (column, index) => 
    <SortableColumnEntry 
      key={column} 
      index={index}
      column={column} />)
```

It all started to work.

At the moment the `column` values are unique and associated with a single entry - later on it would be good to add `id` field to the state.

Comment: This just tripped me up. Thank you for posting the answer! :)